# Use symlinks for zero downtime web delopyment

Tags: apache2, symbolic-link

I have a big website where all the files are in the `public_html` folder.

Here's the structure :

```
-public_html/ 
    - app/
    - public/
    - vendor/
    - index.php
    - test /
        - app /
        - public/
        - vendor/
        - index.php
```

We're working on a new version. It's accessible via  different URL (test.domain.com), and all the files are in the `/test` folder.

At the moment, when we want to make the new changes live (available to domain.com), we copy the files from the `test/` folder to the root of the `public_html/` folder, and overwrite the existing ones. This isn't convenient when deploying a completely new version because there are many files to deploy/overwrite, it takes a lot of time and the website isn't accessible or properly working during that time.

For the next big version, I'd like to try something different : making a symlink that redirects `public_html/` to `public_html/test/` instead. This way, as soon as the symlink is created, the users will see the files in the `test/` folder instead, which contains the new version.

Does this approach work? I've read somewhere that I'd have to delete the `public_html/` folder before creating the symlink, is that true, and is there a way to get around it if it is?

Is there a better way to do this and achieve "zero downtime development", or pretty close to it?

Comment: Couldn't you just change apache or nginx to look at `public_html/test` to be the root of the production site?  Then you could create `public_html/test2` for the next version?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use symbolic links, yes, you will have to move or `public_html` to make it a link. You could do something like:

```
- public_html → production
- production
    - app/
    - public/
    - vendor/
    - index.php
- test /
    - app /
    - public/
    - vendor/
    - index.php
```

`production` and `test` are both outside of `public_html`, and `public_html` is a link to `production`. Then rename `production` and `test` as needed.

Comment: Disclosure: I upvoted your answer and the additional rep might be taken away by @shog9 at any moment. **>:-)**